# MySQL: Ignore error (#1054) and only SET existing columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

**Kontext:**

I have a programm that splits a source database table vertically into two partitions:

Source:

```
id | col1 | col2
1  | v1_1 | v1_2
2  | v2_1 | v2_2
```

Partition #1:

```
id | col1
1  | v1_1
2  | v2_1
```

Partition #2:

```
id | col2
1  | v1_2
2  | v2_2
```

For the client/user it should always look like he has only one table. When he selects all data, the application merges the partitions to one table.

Architecture:

```
Client <--> Server <--> Databases (MySQL)
```

The Client sends parameters to the server. The Server creates and executes a MySQL query on the DBMS and returns a result (depending on the operation/query).

**Problem on update operation:**

The Client sends a request to the HTTP Server with the updated data:

```
HTTP1.1 | PUT
body: {
    db:'Partition_1',
    table: 'test_table',
    data: [
        {id:1, col1:'w1_1', col2:'w1_2'}
    ]
}
```

The server creates following statement:

```
UPDATE 'Partition_1'.'test_table' SET col1='w1_1' AND col2='w1_2';
```

This will result in an error#1054 because the first partition don't know the column 'col2'! (And the second partition don't know 'col1')

I don't want to add parameters to the request. **Is there a way to ignore the error and just set the existing columns?**

(-> This should update the first partition. A similar request will be send for the second partition.)

Comment: If the client knows which partition to update, why doesn't it know which columns are in that partition?

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to make it ignore columns that don't exist. You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to find out the columns in a table on a specific server, and filter out unknown columns that way.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, the client knows the columns of each partition, but then i have to add 'partition logic' to the client and i wanted the server to do that. The server-side option with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` would work too, but i have no idea how much more code it would be. Can you specify your second comment? Maybe with some Pseudocode, so i can see the additional code and choose one option (client-side or server-side)?! BTW.: I am using JavaScript/NodeJS and Express for the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` query to update both the colums, e.g:

```
update t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
set t1.col1 = 10, t2.col2 = 10 where t1.id = 1;
```

Here's **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84ece/2/0)**.

Comment: I think the problem is that the code that's creating the query doesn't know which columns are in which table. Otherwise he could just remove the nonexisting columns.

Comment: @Barmar is right. And the partitions are on different databases and can be on other servers. so i cannot join the tables..... but thank you guys for your fast answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to filter the columns to just the ones that exist on that server. The following query will tell you which columns are valid:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_schema = 'Partition_1'
AND table_name = 'test_table'
AND column_name IN ('col1', 'col2');
```

You can then use the results of this to construct the assignments in the `UPDATE` query.

BTW, to assign to multiple columns, you separate them with `,`, not `AND`:

```
UPDATE test_table SET col1 = 'w1_1', col2 = 'w1_2' WHERE id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your help...

I solved it by changing the parameters of the requests. The Client now only sends the values of the columns which are contained in the table.

I didn't changed the server because he shouldn't know the datamodel of the databases.